# Getting the data from firebase database based on conditions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[This is the link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XTVB.png)

I want to get the msg from the above data where sender equals to salam..can any body help me out how to write query in firebase database(Android)..I am new to this firebase..

Comment: Please remove the link from your question. Links break and if that happens, it invalidates the question. Please include your Firebase structure as TEXT please, no images. You can obtain that from the Firebase Console->Three dots on right->Export JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will be pretty straightforward, but there are multiple ways you can implement the query listeners depending on your use case. If you only want to read your data once, you can setup the following query.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.child("messages").orderByChild("sender").equals("salam")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener({...}));
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write for the startup tutorial and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference for the full documentation.